# How to select text based on the search using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Here is my code

```
List<WebElement> elementsList       =dr.findEements(By.xpath(".//[@id='messageBoxForm']/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div"));
    Iterator<WebElement> itr = elementsList.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext())
    {
      System.out.println(itr.next().getText());
      WebElement element = (WebElement)itr.next();
      element.click();} `
```

I am getting output :

> Bio
>
> Bio mr
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException   at
>   java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)

Comment: Do not call NEXT 2 times. This is fine :  while(itr.hasNext())  BUT remove next() from here : System.out.println(itr.next().getText());

Comment: i have  removed and executed then this Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList$Itr cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.WebElement

Comment: yes because yo are going to store string array data to web element.

Comment: It should be like String element = itr.next();

Answer (score 0):

Like helpinghands has mentioned , you may need to reference to the itr.next() to a Webelement. Code given below.

```
while(itr.hasNext()){
  WebElement element = (WebElement)itr.next();
  System.out.println(element.getText());
  element.click();
 }
```

Comment: Not getting any exception but unable to click on the returned values

Comment: If you can share the output or some source part of the html we can help you better

Answer (score 0):

You can also perform the same task using enhanced for-loop as:

```
foreach(WebElement element : elementsList ){
    System.out.println(element.getText());
    element.click();
}
```